# python package compile build_ext in linux from other directory (seqlearn package)

Tags: python, linux, unix, compilation

I downloaded seqlearn python package (at `https://github.com/larsmans/seqlearn`). I want to use seqlearn from its source directory without installing, so I try to compile first on linux.

The files are at `/home/user/Downloads/seqlearn-master/seqlearn-master/`
I can run 
`python setup.py build_ext --inplace` perfectly 
in the `/home/user/Downloads/seqlearn-master/seqlearn-master/` directory.

However, I want to launch python notebook in my home directory, so I tried `python /home/user/Downloads/seqlearn-master/seqlearn-master/setup.py build_ext --inplace` in my home directory , but it shows

```
ValueError: 'seqlearn/_decode/bestfirst.pyx' doesn't match any files
```

So I can't really compile from my home directory, anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to see options:

```
python setup_telnet.py --help build_ext
```

and use --build-lib option to set other directory.

```
python setup.py  build_ext --build-lib <other directory>
```